# Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect when using PHP function end()

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application I am working with an array provided by an API. This array is called `$client_details` for all intensive purposes.

This array contains further nested arrays, in this instance I am looking at Plans. To access the first Plan for a client I can use something very simple, such as the below:

`{{ $client_data['Plans'][0]['AccessNumber'] }}{{ $client_data['Plans'][0]['PlanTypeId'] }}`

Essentially, go into `Plans` within `$client_details` then go into the first index and look for the key `AccessNumber`.

Some users have multiple `Plans` so the index for the lastest entry is likely to be 1, 2, or 3, not 0.

To get around this I tried the following:

`{{ end($client_data['Plans'])['AccessNumber'] }}{{ end($client_data['Plans'])['PlanTypeId'] }}`

This uses the PHP function [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

But for users that only have a single plan, using `end()` throws the error mentioned in the title.

**Update**

I stopped converting `$client_details` to a collection and then it had no issue, given this, is a collection fundamentally different to an array?

Comment: Could you add the output of `dd($client_data['Plans'])` to your question?

Comment: Yes, I will add it

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with collections Laravel provides a number of methods you can use on the collection.  In your case you are looking for the last() method.  See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-last).  If you are working with arrays you can use the array_last() helper method.  See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-last).

Comment: Would that also work when accessing multidimensional arrays?

Comment: It will get the last element of the array you run the operation on.